# Minimizing perimeter and area of the section obtained by intersection of a given line passing through a point, and the conic.

Tags: conic-sections

Suppose I have any second degree conic and a point $P$ lying *within* the conic. A family of lines pass through this point $P$. We have to find the line for which the area of the corresponding section is minimised. And separately, we want to find a second line, for which the perimeter is minimised. Given is a example traced out in desmos, where we want to minimise the area $[ABC]$ and separately minimise perimeter of triangle $ABC$.

[image]

And here is another example, to illustrate that we want to minimize the area and perimeter for a general second degree conic, showing the situation for a parabola. Where we want to find the inclination of the straight line through P so that the perimeter of the yellow part is maximum. And we want to find a separate condition so that the area is maximum (These are two questions). [image]

I decided to work on a simpler problem first, that of a pair of straight lines. One may quite easily workout the case by using the general equation of a pair of straight lines, that is given by

$$ ax^2  + 2hxy + by^2 + 2gx + 2fy  + c = 0$$

and solving for points in common with $y = mx + c$, and just minimising the determinant, perimeter may be worked out using the distance formula. However a similar method doesn't seem plausible for the other cases. I thought a geometrical interpetration of the same might be a bit better.

My question is, how can we interpret and solve this problem by geometrical or visual arguments? If not, how can we generalise the same for a general second degree conic?

The problem was posed in a high school examination, and is thought to have a nice geometrical answer, which I haven't been able to figure out.

**EDIT:** After fiddling a bit, I figured out that for a pair of straight lines, the minimum perimeter is achieved when the line touches a circle which has the pair of tangents given by the pair of straight lines, I suppose considering a non Euclidean plane would help to handle the other cases geometrically? My attempts at doing it have failed.

Comment: It is not clear to me which area you want to minimize.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I have added more information and another example

Comment: Just intuitively/by symmetry, it would seem that to minimize area, $AB$ should be the line parallel to the directrix for a parabola, or either the major or minor axis which passes through $P$.

Comment: The problem is for a general conic, although I suppose such intuitive methods are the way to go. I do not however understand how intuition would lead the way for perimeter.

Answer (score 1):

Parabola case.

Without loss of generality we can assume that the parabola is $y=ax^2,$ $a>0$. Let $P=(x_0,y_0)$. Let the line passing through $P$ has slope $m$ and cuts the parabola at $-x_1<0$ and $x_2>0$. Then the area of the bounded region between the line and the parabola is
$$A=a\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2}2(x_2+x_1)-a\frac{x_2^3+x_1^3}3=a\frac{(x_2+x_1)^3}6.$$
So we need to minimize $x_2+x_1=\frac1a\sqrt\Delta$ where
$$\Delta=m^2-4ax_0m+4ay_0.$$
So $m=2ax_0$.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following heuristic arguments for the area case.

For the simplicity assume that the point $P$ is the origin $(0,0)$. Suppose that the line $\ell$ passing through the point $P$ and points $P_1$ and $P_2$ on the conic, provides the local extremum of the cut area. Then $|PP_1|=|PP_2|$ otherwise we can both increase and decrease the cut area, rotating $\ell$ around $P$ on a small angle. Thus $P=\frac{P_1+P_2}2$ and so $P_1=-P_2$. Let $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$. Plugging the coordinates of $P_1$ and $P_2$ into the equation of the conic we obtain that
$gx_1+fy_1=0$ and $ax_1^2  + 2hx_1y_1 + by^2_1 + c = 0$. In the nondegenerated case this system should lead to a quadratic equation for $x_1$ or $y_1$.

More technical approach is to affinely transform the conic to one of canonical forms. Since the areas are changed proportionally, it suffices to consider canonical forms.

*Parabola*. It was already considered in Bob Dobbs' [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804765/minimizing-perimeter-and-area-of-the-section-obtained-by-intersection-of-a-given/4810758#4810758).

*Ellipse.* The canonical conic is the circle and the line crossing $P$ cuts a segment from the circle. Since the area of the cut segment is monotonically increasing function of the length $|P_1P_2|$ of its chord $P_1P_2$, we have to minimize this chord length. Since the product $|PP_1|\cdot |PP_2|$ is constant, by the inequality between the arithmetic and geometric means, the length $|P_1P_2|=|P_1P|+|PP_2|$ attains maximum when $|P_1P|=|P_2P|$.

*Hyperbola.* Choosing the respective coordinate system, we can ensure that the equation of the hyperbola is $y=\frac 1x$, $P=(x_0,y_0)$, and $x_0,y_0>0$. Suppose that a line $\ell$ passes through $P$ and points $P_1=\left(x_1,\frac 1{x_1}\right)$ and $P_1=\left(x_2,\frac 1{x_2}\right)$ of the hyperbola such that $x_1<x_2$. Then the cut area equals $$\frac{1/x_1+1/x_2}{2}(x_2-x_1)-\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{x_2^2-x_1^2}{x_1 x_2}-\ln\frac{x_2}{x_1}.$$
...

Comment: I have awarded the bounty to this answer, even though it isnt a complete answer to my problem (it is complete for the area case, however the perimeter case is more puzzling), since it would be awarded to the other answer automatically I suppose

Comment: @ShivanshJaiswal As far as I remember, the bounty is awarded automatically either to an accepted answer or, if there is no accepted answer, then, I guess, the half-size bounty is awarded to the most scored answer, provided it has at least +2 score. From the other hand, my opinion concerning bounty awards is that in order to confirm that the bounty offer  was fair and to acknowledge efforts of all bounty aspirants, a bounty should be given to the best answer, provided it is more or less advanced, although it can be imperfect or incomplete.

Comment: Finally, it seems that the perimeter case can be considered similarly to the area case, but we need to formulate the condition of a local extremum for it.

Comment: Please check my edit.